# jquery fancybox load times and unique urls

Tags: jquery, url, fancybox, loading

With fancybox (v2), how can I create a unique url that, upon load, displays the fancybox with iframe content. I have it working great with inline content (ex. www.mysite.com/index.html#idgoeshere), but don't know what the url or js should contain in order to load the fancybox, and within it, a specific iframe or ajax.txt page.

What I am trying to achieve, is by going to a link like:

www.mysite.com/index.html#iframe.html

Load the index page, with the fancybox window opened, and the iframe.html page loaded into the fancybox window (alternatively it can be a .txt file loaded via ajax too).

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a>
```

Fancybox

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) { 
$.fancybox({
content: $(window.location.hash).html()
});
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Kyle