# jquery fancybox, iframe or ajax, load with url

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, iframe, fancybox

With fancybox (v2), how can I create a unique url that, upon load, displays the fancybox with iframe content. I have it working great with inline content (ex. www.mysite.com/index.html#idgoeshere), but don't know what the url or js should contain in order to load the fancybox, and within it, a specific iframe or ajax.txt page.

What I am trying to achieve, is by going to a link like:

www.mysite.com/index.html#iframe.html

Load the index page, with the fancybox window opened, and the iframe.html page loaded into the fancybox window (alternatively it can be a .txt file loaded via ajax too).

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a>
```

Fancybox

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    $.fancybox({
    content: $(window.location.hash).html()
});
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Kyle

***Update***

Thanks for everyones help!! Here is what ended up working great for me. I saved our my content into separate html files and then called them with fancybox.iframe

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
     'scrolling'   : 'no'   
    });
    if (window.location.hash !== "") {
        $(window.location.hash).click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: me think you wish to decrease da load time

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery fancybox load times and unique urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251905/jquery-fancybox-load-times-and-unique-urls)

Comment: Don't repeat the same question, edit the older one if you want to elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the examples on [the Fancybox site](http://fancybox.net) The Fancybox action is based entirely on the href of the link. So, if you load up the page and then update the href of a link on the page to point to `iframe.html` before calling `.fancybox` on it, then it should work as expected. Warning: Untested code off the top of my head to follow…

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#target').attr('href', window.location.hash.substring(1)).fancybox();
});
```

The substring call is needed to remove the `#` from the hash string returned from `window.location.hash`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @jxpk777, would the #target be the .fancybox class?

Comment: Yes, whatever the target element is for replacing into that content, whatever you intend to eventually call `.fancybox` on. I do agree with Joe that using the location hash isn't a great idea. Probably something with the query string is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hashtag is a bad idea because sites like Google and Facebook often ignore them.

Instead, use window.history.replacestate in the afterLoad function of fancybox.

For example:

```
afterLoad:function(){
    window.history.replaceState({},"Fancybox","/url-to-set");
}
```

Weird thing about replaceState is that the first two arguments don't matter (as far as I know). The only thing that matters is the final argument "/url-to-set". You want to set this as the unique url that you would like to have as your url.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but would this pop up the fancybox with the content onload everytime? I am looking to be able to only have it popup with a specific url call. Thanks.